# Insert data in Go API using nested objects(structs)

Tags: postgresql, go, mux

I'm creating a Golang API, but hit a blocker. For every POST, this is what I get:
`"error": "sql: converting argument $2 type: unsupported type main.Data, a struct"`

I'd like my data to be of format

```
        "name": "test",
        "other": {
            "age": "",
            "height": ""
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this? See the code below, what I've tried so far.

model.go

```
type Data struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Other *Other `json:"other,omitempty"`
}

type Other struct {
    Age     string `json:"host,omitempty"`
    Height string `json:"database,omitempty"`
}

func (d *Data) Create(db *sql.DB) error {
    err := db.QueryRow(
        "INSERT INTO configs(name, other) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id",
        d.Name, &d.Other).Scan(&d.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

controller.go

```
...
func (a *App) createData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var d Data
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

    if err := decoder.Decode(&d); err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
        fatalError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid request")
        return
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if err := d.Create(a.DB); err != nil {
        fatalError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    jsonResponse(w, http.StatusCreated, d)
}
```

I expected the db to be populated with the data of format

```
        "name": "test",
        "other": {
            "age": "",
            "height": ""
        }
    }
```

But fails with error:

```
"error": "sql: converting argument $2 type: unsupported type main.Data, a struct"
```

Comment: Scan the other JSON in a string. After that, you can convert it to JSON.

Comment: can you please explain this?

Comment: The DB driver scans every column as []byte which is then translated into datatype by default it won't scan value of jsonb to a struct, either you would have to write a custom scanner function or read the column in string and json Unmarshal it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I scan a jsonb column to a slice of struct/pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980685/how-do-i-scan-a-jsonb-column-to-a-slice-of-struct-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this modification:

```
import "encoding/json"

func (d *Data) Create(db *sql.DB) error {
   var jsonOther string
   if d.Other != nil {
      jsonOther, _ = json.Marshal(d.Other)
      err := db.QueryRow(
         "INSERT INTO configs(name, other) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id",
         d.Name, jsonOther).Scan(&d.ID)
      if err != nil {
          return err
      }
      return nil
 }
```

Notice that the `Other` object is explicitly serialized to JSON and passed as a string